# If I install a self-compiled package using dpkg, will it get clobbered by unattended-upgrades?

Tags: apt, dpkg, compiling, pinning

I've compiled and installed my own build of `nginx` in order to add a module that doesn't come with the built-in version.  Roughly, I'm doing:

```
apt-get build-dep nginx
apt-get source nginx
cd nginx-1.6.2
# ... add module flag to debian/rules
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
dpkg -i ../nginx-full_1.6.2-5+deb8u2_amd64.deb
```

Now, when I use `dpkg -l '*nginx*'` to show what nginx I have installed, I see:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name               Version        Architecture   Description
+++-==================-==============-==============-=========================================
un  nginx              <none>         <none>         (no description available)
ii  nginx-common       1.6.2-5+deb8u2 all            small, powerful, scalable web/proxy serve
un  nginx-doc          <none>         <none>         (no description available)
un  nginx-extras       <none>         <none>         (no description available)
ii  nginx-full         1.6.2-5+deb8u2 amd64          nginx web/proxy server (standard version)
un  nginx-light        <none>         <none>         (no description available)
```

My worry is that if upstream releases a new minor version of nginx, unattended-upgrades will replace my self-compiled version with the distro binary that doesn't have my custom module compiled in.  Will this happen?  If so, is there a way to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always freeze the package version by

```
sudo apt-mark hold nginx-common nginx-full
```

These packages will not be updated.

Comment: Note though that this tends to introduce the lack of updates from the Ubuntu team (such as security updates), which will introduce its own myriad of issues (and most of those updates are critical)

Comment: @ThomasWard That is true. But is OP wants a custom package this is the only way. I suggest to track security updates and re-compile the package with the patches.

Comment: Right, but I was posting that as an informational bullet point in addition to the question is all.  :)

Comment: So to be sure: if I don't `apt-mark hold` to prevent automatic updates, I can expect them to get clobbered?  There isn't something about the fact that I self-compiled (and it's not signed by upstream maintainers) that would cause it to be considered somehow different?

Comment: If you don't hold the package, it may be replaced by a newer version from Ubuntu repos.